# library doesn't load properly

Tags: javascript

i created a flipbook with help of turn.js.

on my local machine everything works fine, but i load it on my test environment. the turn.js constructor function doesn't work. i have there the following code:

```
$('#flipbook').turn();
```

in my test environment i get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'turn'
```

do you have an idea what could be the problem, the file turn.js is loaded (i proved it in the loaded resources).

thanks in advance :)

Comment: The error basically says that your $('#flipbook') object does not contain the method 'turn'. This can happen if you are calling the function before its definition is loaded.

Comment: Do you have more than one library in your page? Can you try to reproduce the error in a http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: yes i know. therefore i checked if the library was loaded at the time i call this function. and the file was loaded. when i use this on localhost the same code works. just on my test environment i get this error

Comment: Are you sure the path to the flipbook script is correct?

Comment: ohh. i found the error. i loaded the same jquery 2x. once before i load turn.js and once after. this way the 2. load of jquery overrides the old one. so i have then no method turn. thanks anyway. (good that i haven't written this code, because this is so an real beginners error :))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be because it is not loading turn.js properly.

Make sure you are loading the files in the correct way.

**Make sure jQuery is loaded first, then turn.js, then your code.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="turn.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#flipbook").turn();
</script>
```

Also, when you say you are sure turn.js is being loaded, how can you tell? Can you view the code in turn.js in firebug?

Comment: Make sure you spell `javascript` correctly.  Or better yet, just omit the type attribute entirely.

Comment: @Dennis Updated with correct spelling. I have always been taught to use the type attribute. Is this wrong?

Comment: i always type <scr tab tab and then visual studio does the rest for me :)

Comment: `language=javascript` is deprecated so *definitely* don't use that. `type=text/javascript` is redundant and I've seen a number of questions on StackOverflow arise because the OP misspelled it, which meant the browser didn't know what language it was trying to parse.  HTML5 states that if `type` is omitted, use JavaScript which I'm pretty sure was done because it is backwards compatible.

Comment: @Dennis Thanks for the heads up, I'll keep that in mind next time I come to use some JS